# Why does Integral Calculator not include -1152 for the solved integral of $(h^2 + 6h + 9) dh / (2.4k - kh)$ I am calculating for a Tank Problem?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am using https://www.integral-calculator.com/ to follow how to do calculations for an integral $(h^2 + 6h +9) dh / (2.4k - kh)$ for a tank filling and emptying problem.

The calculations are for the tank filling part with laminar flowing oil.
The question says that it takes 15 minutes to fill the tank from 1.2m to 1.8m above outlet, so I need to find constant k here.

I know how to work out the next part for the tank emptying using that constant k in $(h^2 +6h +9) dh / (kh)$.

As can be seen in the screenshot below, I got this calculation correct below

-$(5H - 12)^2 / 50k - 54(5H - 12) / 25k - 729 ln (5H - 12) / 25k + C $

**But with this calculation below, Integral calculator does not have -1152 that I have calculated, why is this ?**

**$[( 25H^2  + 420H - 1152) + ( 1458 ln (5H - 12) ) ] / 50k + C$**

[image: Integral Calculator Solution for Tank Question]

**This is the way I have calculated between the 2 parts I mentioned above**

We want to simplify this $-(5H - 12)^2 / 50k - 54(5H - 12) / 25k - 729 ln (5H - 12) / 25k + C $

Least common denominator of 50k , 25k , 25k is 50k

= $- ((5H - 12)^2 / 50k ) - ( (2 * 54) (5H - 12) / (2 * 25k) ) -  ( (2 * 729 ln) (5H - 12) / (2 * 25k) ) + C $

= $- ( (5H - 12)^2 / 50k )  -  ( 108 (5H - 12) / 50k) ) -  ( (1458 ln) (5H - 12) / 50k ) + C $

Let's expand

= $- ( (5H - 12)(5H - 12) / 50k ) - ( 540H - 1296) / 50k) ) - ( (1458 ln) (5H - 12) / 50k ) + C  $

=  $ - ( ( (5H * 5H) - (12 * 5H) - (12 * 5H) + (-12 * -12) ) / 50k ) - ( 540H - 1296) / 50k) ) -  ( (1458 ln) (5H - 12) / 50k ) + C $

= $ - ( ( (25H^2) - (60H) - (60H) + (144) ) / 50k ) - ( 540H - 1296) / 50k) ) -  ( (1458 ln) (5H - 12) / 50k ) + C $

= $ - [ ( 25H^2 - 120H + 144) + (540H - 1296) + (1458 ln (5H - 12) ) ] / 50k + C  $

= $ - [ ( 25H^2  + 420H - 1152) + ( 1458 ln (5H - 12) ) ] / 50k + C $

**Does anybody have any ideas that can help me solve this thanks ?**

Comment: Well, think about what “$+C$” actually means...

Comment: + C is the constant of integration that is used for the indefinite integral . 

Are you suggesting that the - 1152 is related to this and that is why it is taken out.

The definite integral happens after this when the integral is integrated between the limits of 1.2m and 1.8m.

Just trying to get an understanding on why - 1152 is taken out.

Comment: Yes. If you have the antiderivative $(\cdots) - 1152 + C$, then you can let $D=C-1152$ and write your antiderivative as $(\cdots) + D$ instead. Since $C$ was an arbitrary constant, the constant $D=C-1152$ will also be arbitrary, so there's no useful information contained in the number $-1152$. (And when you insert the bounds in the definite integral, it would cancel out anyway.)

Comment: To me it seems the main reason - 1152 is ignored in the integration, is because when it changes from indefinite to definite integral it cancels out.
So - (-1152) - (-1152) = 1152 - 1152 = 0

When you say D = C - 1152, I think you are just showing that -1152 can be included in the constant of integration if you want.

To me, I can see that for a solved indefinite integral, a number on its own and not part of a variable like h in this example can be ignored because when you do  definite integral it cancels out.

What is the purpose of having a constant of integration when it cancels?

Comment: So for $$\int 2 \sin x \cos x \, dx = \sin^2 x + C = -\cos^2 x + D = -\frac12 \cos 2x + E,$$ which constant of integration would you consider the “most natural” to use? You simply cannot say that one arbitrary constant is “better” than some other. Regarding the purpose, if you're going to use it for computing a definite integral $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = F(b)-F(a)$, you don't need to include a constant, since you just need *some* antiderivative $F$, not the most general one. But in other cases, like solving an ODE with an initial condition, you will need to worry about the constant.

Comment: OK, so it looks like my understanding is correct regarding the constant of integration and -1152 can be ignored for my situation because I am computing a definite integral and they cancel out.  
I am correct with my understanding on this aren't I ?

Not sure what you mean when you say just need some antiderivative , not the most general one ?

I am not sure what you mean by an ODE with an initial condition, when you need a constant for the integration.
May you please clarify this for me.
Still can't see a situation when constant of integration is useful in the integration process.

Comment: Understanding constant in $∫ 2 sin  cos   = sin^2 + = −cos 2 +  = −1/2 cos 2 + $ , is a different problem all together from mine.

I've run $∫ 2 sin  cos   $ in integral calculator and it gave sin^2  +  , so I suppose C is the most natural to use.

For next part in ANTIDERIVATIVE COMPUTED BY MAXIMA: it becomes - cos^2  x + C  
and then when it comes to doing the definite integral - 1/2 cos 2x is used between the limits.

The thing I always wonder with these types of integrals is why does sin change to cos or cos change to sin when they get integrated ?

Comment: @HansLundmark
Hi Hans, just wondering if you have had a chance to look at my previous replies regarding understanding when a constant becomes more important in the integration ?

Comment: @HansLundmark  Hi Hans, just a quick question on understanding ln (5H - 12 ) in this integration.

The integration goes from - [ ( 25H^2  +  420H - 1152) + ( 1458 ln (5H - 12) ) ] / 50k + C       to     (1458 ln (6) - 1458 ln(3) - 297) / 50k      for between limits of H = 1.2m to H = 1.8m to fill tank.
If you put H = 1.2 into ln (5H - 12 ) it equals ln ( (5 * 1.2) - 12) = ln (6 - 12) = ln (-6)
When I calculate ln (-6) on a calculator it is an error. 
Why is it that for this situation - [ 1458 ln (-6) ] becomes positive 1458 ln (6) when ln (-6) can be an error ?

Comment: It's not $\ln(5h-12)$, it's $\ln|5h-12|$, with absolute value signs.

Comment: What is the difference between ln(5h−12) and  ln|5h−12| with the absolute values ?
How does  ln|5h−12| work with absolute values ?

Comment: $\ln|-6|=\ln 6$.